# How to use FirestoreAnimatedList in SliverChildListDelegate?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver, flutter-packages

I am try use `SliverList` for render data from backend (Firestore) in list. But I get error:

> The following assertion was thrown building
>   NotificationListener: Incorrect use of
>   ParentDataWidget.
>
> Flexible widgets must be placed inside Flex widgets. Flexible(no
>   depth, flex: 1, dirty) has no Flex ancestor at all. The ownership
>   chain for the parent of the offending Flexible was:   RepaintBoundary
>   ← IndexedSemantics ← NotificationListener ←
>   KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree ← SliverList ← Viewport
>   ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#1e502] ← Semantics ← ⋯

```
          new CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: <Widget>[              
                    SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                       new Flexible(
                            child:
                            new FirestoreAnimatedList(
                              query: reference
                                  .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                                  .snapshots(),
                              itemBuilder: (_, DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                                  Animation<double> animation) {
                                return new Widget(
                                  snapshot: snapshot,
                                  animation: animation,
```

But if I remove `Flexible` it give error:

> The following assertion was thrown during performResize(): Vertical
>   viewport was given unbounded height.
>
> Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In
>   this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of
>   vertical space in which to expand. This situation typically happens
>   when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
>   If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no
>   need to use a viewport because there will always be enough vertical
>   space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column instead.
>   Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a
>   ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size the height of the viewport to the sum
>   of the heights of its children. User-created ancestor of the
>   error-causing widget was:    FirestoreAnimatedList

If I replace `FirestoreAnimatedlist` with `Placeholder()` there is no problem:

```
          new CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: <Widget>[              
                    SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                        Placeholder(),
        Placeholder(),
        Placeholder(),
```

How I can solve?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

`Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget` error in Flutter occurs when the Child widget has not matched the parent widget.

In your case, this error happens due to the `Flexible()` widget. It is not a descendant of a Flex widget:

```
 new CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: <Widget>[              
                    SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                       new Flexible(
                            child:
                            new FirestoreAnimatedList()
                               ...
```

To solve this error, your child widget must have the expected parent widget. Some of the widget and their parent widgets are:

| Widget | Parent Widget |
| --- | --- |
| [Expanded()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) | [Row()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html), [Column()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html), [Flex()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex-class.html) |
| [Flexible()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) | [Row()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html), [Column()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html), [Flex()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex-class.html) |
| [Positioned()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) | [Stack()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) |
| [TableCell()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TableCell-class.html) | [Table()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html) |

Here Flexible is a descendant of Flex:

```
Flex(
  direction: Axis.horizontal,
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Row is also a Flex widget:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
  ],
)
```

And so is Column:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Another option is to just get rid of the Flexible widget by wrapping your widget in a [Container()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html):

```
Container(
  child: MyWidget(),
)
```